# Merge local git repo with remote one

Tags: git

I have a quite straightforward remote git repository:

```
*---*---(a)---*---(b, HEAD) (master)
```

Also I've been working in local repo of the project, which initial state corresponds to the state after commit **(a)**, and that has many branches:

```
(a')---*-------------*-----------* (my-master)
        \___________/___________/__ (my-dev)
         \______________..._______/ (feature, hotfix branches)
```

However, initial commit of the local repo wasn't obtained properly (i.e. with git commands), but by copying project files (hence the name (a') since it corresponds to the same state as (a) but is different from Git's point of view). Now I want to merge my local changes with remote repo, but also 'bind' somehow initial commit of local repo to commit **(a)** in order to get the following picture:

```
*---*---(a)---*-----------------------(b)-- (merge-commit, HEAD) (master)
          \________________________________/ (my-master)
                  \___________/___________/__ (my-dev)
                   \______________..._______/ (feature, hotfix branches)
```

What is the most proper way to do this?

Comment: Add the real remote repository, fetch from it, and then rebase all your branches to be based on the real `a` commit.

Comment: Just answered a connected question, hope that helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245460/move-the-old-git-history-to-a-new-already-created-and-edited-repo/30291006#30291006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) comment I found the solution that is appropriate for my purposes.

```
# add remote repo and fetch it
git remote add repo <repo_addr>
git fetch repo

# create new branch for rebasing onto
# here 'a' is hash of the commit (a)
git checkout a
git branch my-huge-feature

# rebasing my-master branch onto my-huge-feature
git checkout my-master
git rebase my-huge-feature

# fast-forwarding my-huge-feature pointer
git checkout my-huge-feature
git merge my-master
```

After these steps I get my local commit history integrated into remote repo history (pushing my-huge-feature omitted).

However, `rebase` command does not save branching history, so remote repo will store my commits in a single branch. Although it is ok for me, I would greatly appreciate if this answer would be supplied with method to preserve branching history.